# Some part not covering in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I wrote a trigger and want to increase my code coverage.

Trigger:

```
trigger CreateContactRole on Opportunity (after insert,after update) {

        List<OpportunityContactRole> newContactRoleList=new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
        List<OpportunityContactRole> oldContactRoleList=new List<OpportunityContactRole>();

        Set<Id> OppId=new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> ContactId=new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> OpporId =new Set<Id>();

        if(Trigger.isInsert){
            for(Opportunity oppObj: Trigger.new)
            {
                if(oppObj.Key_Negotiator__c !=null && (oppObj.Service_Offered__c != Null || oppObj.Project_Name__c != null || oppObj.Account != Null || oppObj.StageName !=Null
                   || oppObj.CurrencyIsoCode != Null || oppObj.Name != Null || oppObj.CloseDate != Null || oppObj.Referred_By__c != Null || oppObj.Design_Offices__c !=Null))
                {
                    newContactRoleList.add
                    (
                    new OpportunityContactRole (
                    ContactId=oppObj.Key_Negotiator__c,
                    OpportunityId=oppObj.Id, 
                    Role='Key Negotiator')
                    );
                 }

                 if(oppObj.Partner_in_Charge__c !=null && (oppObj.Service_Offered__c != Null || oppObj.Project_Name__c != null || oppObj.Account != Null || oppObj.StageName !=Null
                   || oppObj.CurrencyIsoCode != Null || oppObj.Name != Null || oppObj.CloseDate != Null || oppObj.Referred_By__c != Null || oppObj.Design_Offices__c !=Null))
                 {
                    newContactRoleList.add
                    (
                    new OpportunityContactRole (
                    ContactId=oppObj.Partner_in_Charge__c,
                    OpportunityId=oppObj.Id, 
                    Role='Partner in Charge')
                    );
                 }

                 if(oppObj.Project_Design_Leader__c !=null && (oppObj.Service_Offered__c != Null || oppObj.Project_Name__c != null || oppObj.Account != Null || oppObj.StageName !=Null
                   || oppObj.CurrencyIsoCode != Null || oppObj.Name != Null || oppObj.CloseDate != Null || oppObj.Referred_By__c != Null))
                 {
                    newContactRoleList.add
                    (
                    new OpportunityContactRole (
                    ContactId=oppObj.Project_Design_Leader__c,
                    OpportunityId=oppObj.Id, 
                    Role='Project Design Leader')
                    );
                 }

            }

        }



        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        Map<id, list<OpportunityContactRole>> OppContactRoleMap = new Map<id, list<OpportunityContactRole>>();
        for(opportunity opp: trigger.new){
            OpporId.add(opp.id);
        }
        list<opportunity> OppContactRole = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id,OpportunityId FROM OpportunityContactRoles)  FROM opportunity WHERE id in : OpporId];
        for(opportunity opp: OppContactRole){
            OppContactRoleMap.put(opp.id, opp.OpportunityContactRoles);
        }


        for(Opportunity oppObj: Trigger.new)
        {
            if(oppObj.Key_Negotiator__c ==null && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id).Key_Negotiator__c !=null && OppContactRoleMap.get(oppObj.id).size() < 4)
            {

                 Opportunity OldoppObj=Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id);     
                 system.debug('--OldoppObj-->>'+OldoppObj);    
                 OppId.add(OldoppObj.id);
                 ContactId.add(OldoppObj.Key_Negotiator__c); 

            }
            else if(oppObj.Key_Negotiator__c!=null && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id).Key_Negotiator__c==null)
            {

                newContactRoleList.add(new OpportunityContactRole (ContactId=oppObj.Key_Negotiator__c, OpportunityId=oppObj.Id, Role='Key Negotiator'));
            }

            if(oppObj.Partner_in_Charge__c ==null && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id).Partner_in_Charge__c !=null && OppContactRoleMap.get(oppObj.id).size() < 4)
            {

                 Opportunity OldoppObj=Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id);     
                 system.debug('--OldoppObj-->>'+OldoppObj);    
                 OppId.add(OldoppObj.id);
                 ContactId.add(OldoppObj.Partner_in_Charge__c); 
                 system.debug('--OldoppObj.Partner_in_Charge__c-->>'+OldoppObj.Partner_in_Charge__c);

            }
            else if(oppObj.Partner_in_Charge__c!=null && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id).Partner_in_Charge__c ==null)
            {
               /*
                Opportunity OldoppObj=Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id);     
                 system.debug('--OldoppObj-->>'+OldoppObj);    
                 OppId.add(OldoppObj.id);
                 ContactId.add(OldoppObj.Partner_in_Charge__c); 
                 */
                newContactRoleList.add(new OpportunityContactRole (ContactId=oppObj.Partner_in_Charge__c, OpportunityId=oppObj.Id, Role='Partner in Charge'));
            }


            if(oppObj.Project_Design_Leader__c ==null && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id).Project_Design_Leader__c !=null && OppContactRoleMap.get(oppObj.id).size() < 4)
            {

                 Opportunity OldoppObj=Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id);     
                 system.debug('--OldoppObj-->>'+OldoppObj);    
                 OppId.add(OldoppObj.id);
                 ContactId.add(OldoppObj.Project_Design_Leader__c); 

            }
            else if(oppObj.Project_Design_Leader__c!=null && Trigger.oldMap.get(oppObj.Id).Project_Design_Leader__c==null)
            {

                newContactRoleList.add(new OpportunityContactRole (ContactId=oppObj.Project_Design_Leader__c, OpportunityId=oppObj.Id, Role='Project Design Leader'));
            }
        } 
        }

        /*    
        if(newContactRoleList.size()>=0 || newContactRoleList.size()!=null)   
            system.debug('--newContactRoleList-->>'+newContactRoleList);
        update newContactRoleList;


        if ( OppId.size()>0) newContactRoleList=[Select Id from OpportunityContactRole where ContactId in : ContactId  and OpportunityId in : OppId];

        if (newContactRoleList.size()>0) 

        Update newContactRoleList;
            system.debug('--newContactRoleList-->>'+newContactRoleList);
        */

        try
    {

        if(newContactRoleList.size()>0 || newContactRoleList.size()!=null) 
        insert newContactRoleList;


        //if ( OppId.size()>0) oldContactRoleList=[Select Id from OpportunityContactRole where ContactId in : ContactId  and OpportunityId in : OppId];


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.debug(e);
        trigger.new[0].addError('Technical error occurred. Please contact to your system administrator or try after some time.'+e);

    }

}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest(seealldata=true)
public class TestCreateContactRole {
    static testmethod void UpdateAccountSubscriptionEmail()
    {   
        Account a = new account();
        a.name='test';
        insert a;

        contact con =new contact();
        con.LastName='Test';
        con.AccountId=a.Id;
        insert con;


        Project__c pro =new Project__c();
        pro.name='test';
        pro.Owner_Developer2__c=a.id;
        pro.Status__c='Vision';
        pro.Project_Type__c='Hotel';
        pro.City__c='SG';
        pro.Country__c='Singapore';
        insert pro;

        opportunity opp=new opportunity();
        opp.AccountId=a.Id;
        opp.name='test';
        opp.StageName= 'Lead';
        opp.CloseDate= System.today(); 
        opp.Contact_Person__c=con.Id;
        opp.Key_Negotiator__c=con.Id;
        opp.Design_Offices__c=a.Id;
        opp.Partner_in_Charge__c=con.Id;
        opp.Project_Design_Leader__c=con.Id;
        opp.Service_Offered__c='Interior Design (HBA)';
        opp.Project_Name__c=pro.id;
        opp.Referred_By__c=con.id;
        opp.Key_Negotiator__c=null;
        //opp.Design_Offices__c=null;
        //opp.Partner_in_Charge__c=null;
        //opp.Project_Design_Leader__c=null;

        insert opp;
        //update opp;

        OpportunityContactRole ocr =new OpportunityContactRole();
        ocr.Opportunityid=opp.id;
        ocr.ContactId=opp.Project_Design_Leader__c;
        ocr.Role='Project Design Leader';
        insert ocr;

        Test.starttest();
        opportunity opp1=new opportunity();
        opp1.AccountId=a.Id;
        opp1.id=opp.id;
        opp1.name='test';
        opp1.StageName= 'Lead';
        opp1.CloseDate= System.today(); 
        opp1.Contact_Person__c=con.Id;
        opp1.Key_Negotiator__c=con.Id;
        opp1.Design_Offices__c=a.Id;
        opp1.Partner_in_Charge__c=con.Id;
        opp1.Project_Design_Leader__c=con.Id;
        opp1.Service_Offered__c='Interior Design (HBA)';
        opp1.Project_Name__c=pro.id;
        opp1.Referred_By__c=con.id;

        update opp1;
        Test.stopTest();
    }

        static testmethod void UpdateAccountSubscriptionEmail1()
    {   
        Account a = new account();
        a.name='test';
        insert a;

        contact con =new contact();
        con.LastName='Test';
        con.AccountId=a.Id;
        insert con;

        opportunity opp=new opportunity();
        opp.AccountId=a.Id;
        opp.name='test';
        opp.StageName= 'Lead';
        opp.CloseDate= System.today(); 
        opp.Contact_Person__c=con.Id;
        opp.Key_Negotiator__c=con.Id;
        opp.Design_Offices__c=a.Id;
        opp.Partner_in_Charge__c=con.Id;
        opp.Project_Design_Leader__c=con.Id;
        opp.Service_Offered__c='Interior Design (HBA)';

        //opp.Key_Negotiator__c=null;

        insert opp;
        //update opp;

        OpportunityContactRole ocr =new OpportunityContactRole();
        ocr.Opportunityid=opp.id;
        ocr.ContactId=opp.Project_Design_Leader__c;
        ocr.Role='Project Design Leader';
        insert ocr;

        Test.starttest();

        opportunity opp1=new opportunity();

        opp1.AccountId=a.Id;
        opp1.id=opp.id;
        opp1.name='test';
        opp1.StageName= 'Lead';
        opp1.CloseDate= System.today(); 
        opp1.Contact_Person__c=con.Id;
        opp1.Key_Negotiator__c=opp.Key_Negotiator__c;
        opp1.Design_Offices__c=a.Id;
        opp1.Partner_in_Charge__c=null;
        opp1.Partner_in_Charge__c=con.Id;
        opp1.Project_Design_Leader__c=con.Id;
        opp1.Service_Offered__c='Interior Design (HBA)';

        update opp1;
        Test.stopTest();
    }


}
```

Some part which is not covered:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First i suggest you to create your own test data in TestSetup. You should check [TestSetup](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring15/TestClasses) method for this. Now in your second oPportunity instance clear this field value `Key_Negotiator__c`  and then create 4+ child `OpportunityContactRole`
record to satisfy your if condition. This will cover your remaining lines.

Also you should use assert and best practices in your test class code.